# PostgreSQL - Get DDL for materialized view

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I need to be able to get the DDL from a materialized view.  We are wanting to track how often a MV gets updated/changed, and I want to be able to automate this process.  I just need the DDL for the MV, not the column names/select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the view definition like this:

```
SELECT pg_get_viewdef('schemaname.mvname');
```

To get the complete DDL statement, prepend the following:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schemaname.mvname AS
```

The only way to track changes in a materialized view definition would be to create an event trigger on `ddl_command_end`.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was after!